# The use of nominative "whom" (as in “persons whom it is foreseeable are likely to...”)

Tags: grammaticality, relative-clauses, relative-pronouns, subordinate-clauses, whom

From  page 48 of *Law: A Very Short Introduction*, by Raymond Wacks:

> In other words, you owe a duty to `persons` **whom** *it is foreseeable* are likely to be harmed by your conduct.

To try to parse this, temporarily overlook '*it is foreseeable*'. Then `persons` is the subject of the verb phrase *are likely to be harmed*. So [according to this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly),
should the relative pronoun for `persons` be **who** instead? Is my parse wrong?

Are the (deleted) comments right: that this style predominates in law texts?
If this is correct grammar, what is the general rule? Is it commonly used in other contexts?

Comment: You might be interested in the topic of ***nominative 'whom'***. It is often covered by a decent usage dictionary, such as *Merriam-Webster's (Concise) Dictionary of English Usage.* One such example, in *MWCDEU* entry "who, whom", page 782: *"Aikman will always have a chilly relationship with coach Barry Switzer, whom Aikman believes is too soft when it comes to player discipline"* -- Peter King, *Sports Illustrated*, 1997.

Comment: This topic of "who versus whom", where the word is the *subject of an embedded content clause* is discussed in the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), pages 466-7, where the *nominative 'whom'* is used by "Dialect B" speakers. *CGEL* states *"That this is another place, however, where it is invalid to talk in terms of hypercorrection. . . . It has to be accepted as an established variant of the standard language."*

Comment: And so, it seems to me that reasonable arguments could probably be made to consider that example in your post to be acceptable in today's standard English.

Comment: Perhaps I ought to explicitly mention that "Dialect A" usage (where speakers would use *"who"* in your example) is mentioned by the 2002 *CGEL* on page 467 as: *"Dialect A, which selects nominative, has more speakers and is the one recommended by the manuals, but there is no reason to say that it is inherently better or more grammatically correct than Dialect B, which selects accusative: the dialects just have different rules."*

Comment: Actually, I think it is a typo missing the preposition *to*. "You owe a duty to persons whom it is foreseeable ***to***."

Comment: Huddleston and Pullum et al are often iconoclasts and contort reason in support of their theories.The "nominative "whom"" does not exist.  In "you owe a duty to persons whom it is foreseeable are likely to be harmed by your conduct.", "*it is foreseeable*" is a free modifier and can be omitted, especially as "*likely*" is stated. With the omission, the "who" becomes obvious, A pair of commas would improve things: "persons who*, it is foreseeable,* are likely to be harmed." -- "who" is unconnected with "it is foreseeable".

Answer (score 9):

***The following is my original answer, which I stand by as being logical and on the face of it applicable, though it does not seem to tell the whole story. See below for a revised answer.***

You are right: it should be *who* here.

This is a simple (and fairly common) case of hyper-correction, where people who are not quite sure how to use *who* and *whom* correctly end up using *whom* in places where it should not be used because they think it sounds ‘fancier’ and therefore more formal (a logical enough thing to think, since *whom* is indeed mostly used in formal contexts). This happens even in places where *whom* is quite clearly impossible to anyone who distinguishes the two forms, such as “I did not know the person whom was sitting next to me”.

In this instance, however, the mistake is easier to understand, even if made by someone who distinguishes *who* and *whom*: the intervening parenthetical phrase “it is foreseeable” probably influenced the choice. It is obvious that *it* in that parenthetical is the subject, which probably made the author think *who(m)* would then have to be an object—having two subjects right next to each other is not common and usually avoided.

---

***Revised answer that tells a fuller story (based on comments by Araucaria and myself below, some of which have been incorporated into the answer itself and therefore deleted to improve the legibility of the comment chain)***

As Araucaria has shown below, there appears to be more to this than meets the eye. This particular construction is not as straightforward as an initial analysis that simply removes the “it is foreseeable” as parenthetical information might suggest, for the following reasons:

1. There are many instances of the oblique-case pronoun *whom* being used in this type of construction, especially in the field of law, but also in literature and elsewhere
2. The deletion properties of the pronoun in these constructions match those normally found with *object* pronouns, rather than subject pronouns

For examples of (1) above, I refer to the quotes unearthed by Araucaria in the comments below and in the comment section of the question itself. They show quite clearly that, whatever prescriptive (or even descriptive) grammar says, forms with *whom* are quite common and widespread, even in proofread, formal texts written by able language users.

If you transpose various elements in the sentence, you really end up with a fairly complex structure.

> … persons whom it is foreseeable are X …

– is made up of a head noun and a following relative clause. The relative clause itself, however, is made up of a *main* clause and a *complement* clause (in layman’s terms often called a *that*-clause). The pronoun (which, being a relative pronoun in a relative clause, must stand at the head of the clause) is really the subject of the complement clause embedded in the main clause. In other words, if we split up the clauses to avoid a relative clause, strange things happen. Compare:

> I have two friends who are fans of Lady Gaga. => I have two friends. They are fans of Lady Gaga.

– where the relative clause is the same as the resulting main clause, except for the pronoun; with:

> I have two friends who(m) I think are fans of Lady Gaga. => I have two friends. I think (that) they are fans of Lady Gaga.

– where the complement clause *(that) they are fans of Lady Gaga* is split up to allow the pronoun to be raised to the head, enabling the containing main clause to function as a relative clause. The relativiser is extrapolated from an embedded clause, rather than being present in the main clause itself. The only thing that could be relativised in the main clause (*it* => *which*) is left alone for semantic reasons: it is not a possible anaphor for the antecedent *persons*

With this much moving around, it is hardly surprising, really, that extrapolation of an embedded subject to become the relativiser in the containing clause can wreak some grammatical-logical havoc. Even with this analysis in mind, I still cannot determine what grammatical role the extrapolated pronoun ought to play in the *relative clause* (as opposed to in the embedded *complement clause*, where it is clearly the subject). It seems, if we go by actual usage, that it can be interpreted as *either* subject *or* object.

One fact that proves that the interpretation as object is real and not just people being confused about when to use *whom* is relativiser deletion. In a relative clause, the relativiser<sup>1</sup> must be present if it is the subject in the clause:

> My friend who loves Lady Gaga.

– but is optional if it plays a non-subject role in the clause:

> The Lady Gaga song (that) my friend loves most. *(object)*
>   The Lady Gaga album (that) my friend gave a 10/10 rating. *(indirect object)*
>   The Lady Gaga dress (that) my friend wrote a school essay about. *(prepositional object)*

In the example from this question, *the relativiser can be deleted*, which clearly shows that it is interpretable as a non-subject element (my guess would be it’s probably some kind of vaguely adverbial element more than a real object):

> [Y]ou owe a duty to persons (who[m]) it is foreseeable are X …

If we consider “it is foreseeable” to be a parenthetical statement and remove it, this deletion is not possible:

> *[Y]ou owe a duty to persons (∅) are X …

This suggests that the relativiser in your sentence (with “it is foreseeable”) plays the role of **non-subject**, and *whom* is appropriate.

On the other hand, if we look closer at the complement clause itself, a very striking and rather annoyingly contradictory phenomenon can be gleaned.

Normally, in English complement clauses, the complementiser (*that*) is optional. In some cases, it sounds clunky to have it, in others it sounds clunky to leave it out—but it is usually not ungrammatical to do either. This is also the case in constructions like the present ones, but *only if the relativiser is a non-subject in the complement clause*. Regardless of what role the (also optional) relativiser *who(m)/which/that* plays in the relative clause (= main clause + complement clause), the complementiser *that* can be left out or kept in as long as the relativiser is not the subject in the complement clause:

> The Lady Gaga album (which) I think (that) my friend is listening to.

Here, both relativiser *which* and complementiser *that* can be left out or kept in with no change of any kind.

If the relativiser is the subject of the complement clause, however, the complementiser appears to be *mandatorily blocked*—it simply *cannot* appear:

> The Lady Gaga album (which) I think (*that) is playing now.

This is most peculiar, and I have absolutely no idea *why* it is so; but it is. Having the complementiser in the sentence here is completely and utterly ungrammatical in any register or form of English I’ve ever seen.

In your sentence here, adding a complementiser makes the sentence quite ungrammatical:

> Persons (who) it is foreseeable (*that) are likely to…

This suggests that the relativiser must be playing the role of **subject**, and *who* is appropriate.

This is rather messy, but it seems to be true: the relativiser here is either both subject and object or neither subject nor object, depending on your point of view. No wonder people get confused about whether to use *who* or *whom*!

---

<sup>1</sup> For present purposes, I consider it unnecessary to distinguish between complementisers and operators (=relativisers), since they are mutually exclusive anyway. I thus use *relativiser* for both *that* and *who(m)*.

Comment: +1. Hypercorrection or a mere typo. No way to know, actually, short of asking Mr Wacks.

Comment: If you search Google books for "who/whom they say has/have", you find that the overwhelming majority use "who", and the ones that use "whom" are for the most part quite recent ... I'd say that what is going on is mainly overcorrection by people who I suspect never learned how to use "whom" properly.

Comment: Possibly the form was attracted to "whom" by the proximity of the preposition "to"; on first reading, I thought it should be "whom" until I parsed out the rest of the phrase.

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry for missing your comment above until now. I've asked a moderator to reinstate the comments.

Comment: @LawArea51Proposal-Commit Actually, most of the comments, I believe have been incorporated into Janus' post.

Comment: @RegDwigнt The OP is wrong. If it were *who*, there would be no use for the word as it would modify absolutely nothing in its clause. I think it's just missing the preposition "to": *You owe a duty to persons whom it is foreseeable **to***.

Comment: @BlackandWhite No, there should definitely not be an extra _to_ there. That would make the entire sentence completely nonsensical. “To persons who(m) it is foreseeable to are likely to” is utter gibberish. I'm not sure what you mean with your first sentence.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet The sentence is nonsensical as it is. Seriously, I have no idea what that's supposed to mean. BUT! For me, adding *to* makes sense. I'll break it down. "You owe a duty to [me]." "It is foreseeable to [me]." That makes sense to me, and this does too: "You owe a duty to the people whom it is foreseeable to."

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Also, I was saying that *who/whom* plays absolutely no role in that relative clause. It is neither the subject nor the object of anything (as it is).

Comment: @Black No, it makes perfect sense as it stands. As a standalone sentence, your rewrite does make some level of sense, but the sentence _continues_.  “X are likely to be harmed by your conduct. You owe a duty to X” – that’s what it means. There’s nothing wrong with “You owe a duty to those who(m) it is foreseeable are likely to be harmed by your conduct” except that it’s a bit clunky. “You owe a duty to those who are foreseeably likely to be harmed by your conduct” is more elegant, since it reduces the complexity of the sentence structure.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Very true, but what does the relative pronoun "who/whom" have to do in the relative clause in the clunky version? Nothing, and that's what doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @BlackandWhite It does have something to do there. It's been extrapolated from the embedded complement clause, but it certainly plays a part. Showing the extrapolated location in single brackets and the trace in double brackets: “persons [who] it is foreseeable [[who]] are likely…”. The only trouble is that the extrapolated function is somewhat indeterminable, despite the trace’s function being quite unambiguously subjective.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet You bring up a good point that I completely missed. I'd further change the sentence to this: *You owe a duty to persons whom it is foreseeable **to** **and who** are likely to be harmed by your conduct.

Comment: @BlackandWhite No, that would mean that you owe a duty to people you foreseeably owe a duty to—a tautology. The point is that “it is foreseeable [that] [they] will likely be harmed by your conduct” is treated as **one** clause embedded into the main clause. You can replace “it is foreseeable [that]” with “you think [that]” if that's clearer: “You owe a duty to persons who you think are likely to be harmed…”, not “You owe a duty to persons who you think and who are likely to be harmed…”.

Answer (score 5):

Please find below a very short answer that agrees with Janus on most points.

> You owe a duty to persons *whom it is foreseeable are likely to be harmed by your conduct.

If the only thing I do is replace the relative pronoun with a personal pronoun and adjust the sentences only just enough to make it work, I get this:

> You owe a duty to persons. It is foreseeable **they** are likely to be harmed by your conduct.

The relative pronoun should therefore have been **who**, not **whom**, despite what lawmakers write (whom are not always the best of writers).

---

So what I did was only this:

- whom → them/they
- change the position of the pronoun to fit a main clause, i.e. before its verb, *are*

The next step was to choose between *they* and *them*, and the obvious choice was *they*.

It is clear that *it is foreseeable* needs to be followed by a finite *that* clause, even though *that* can be omitted—which is unremarkable, as most conjunctions *that* can be omitted.

It is also clear from this that *it is foreseeable* is not parenthetical; the sentence *it is foreseeable they are x* clearly has the same construction, and *it is foreseeable* is clearly not parenthetical there, but a superordinate clause governing a subordinate *that* clause.

---

The reason why some people write *whom* in such cases is contamination; they confuse this type of sentence with a different type:

> ...persons whom I consider to be wrong
>
> ...persons whom one knows to be wrong

These are examples of *accusatives with infinitives*, which indeed require *whom*; notice the infinitives *be*:

> ...persons. I consider **them** to be wrong.
>
> ...persons. One considers **them** to be wrong.

Comment: That part at the end (“them to be wrong”, etc.) makes sense, given how the subject of an infinitive clause is always in oblique case.

Answer (score -3):

Though modern English has nearly lost the distiction between *who* and *whom*, in practice this distiction is still honored by many grammarians and professions like law, where traditions change much slower.

I have to disagree for linguistics reasons, that who is preferred over whom.  *Who* is a nominal form or sometimes referred to as the subject case.  *Whom* is technically a dative case sometimes referred to as the object case.

If you look closely at your example, note that it is *to persons whom*.  The preposition *to* projects a dative case (technically) and will always prefer a dative pronoun. The construction *to whom* is preferred over *to who*, since *who* really wants to be in a subject position which is not the case here.  Again, for emphasis, this distiction is not only becoming lost in modern English, but words with different case forms in English are rare overall.  The who/whom distinction (and its variants) may be one of the last remnants of this.

Which you use is more a matter of *speech register*.  In more formal writing (such as a legal document) this distinction is clearly still more important than in casual speech.

Comment: The basic argument you're making here is incorrect. The case of _who(m)_ (or any relativiser in, as far as I know, any language) is not determined by the case of its antecedent, but by the relativiser’s **own function in the relative clause**. Just because it's “to persons” in the main clause doesn't mean it has to be _whom_ in the relative clause.