# Why does "that" sound odd to me after "said" in these sentences with "as" and "like"?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, subordinate-clauses, that

1. You said **that** he would come to the party.
2. He came to the party, as you said **that** he would.
3. He came to the party, just as you said **that** he would.
4. He came to the party, just like you said **that** he would.

To me, the word *that* seems progressively less acceptable in the sentences above. It sounds unobjectionable in the first sentence ("You said ***that*** he would come to the party"), but it sounds pretty bad to me in the fourth sentence, and also in the third sentence. I can't decide whether it sounds acceptable in the second sentence. In contrast, all of the sentences sound fine to me when *that* is omitted: "...as you said he would," "just as you said he would," "...just like you said he would."

Are my acceptability judgements of these sentences shared by others? If so, why is this? I can't figure out why the use of the word *like* before the clause starting with "you said..." should change the acceptability of the use of *that* before the clause "he would".

Comment: Yes, that's broadly true for me too, although I'm not so sure about the "progressive" bit - I'd say 1 is fine and 2-4 are all pretty strange. Aren't they different *that*s though? To me the one in 1 is introducing a complement of *say*, whereas the ones in 2 - 4 relate to *as / just as / just like* - the meaning is *in accordance with what you said*. Perhaps 1 should be *Just as you said that he would come to the party, he did*, which is just as strange.

Comment: In all your examples *that* is used as a conjunction, which connects a subordinate clause to a preceding verb, and it is sometimes called *the expletive that*. As a general rule, if the sentence feels just as good without the that, if no ambiguity results from its omission, if the sentence is more efficient or elegant without it, then we can safely omit the that. See more information on [this page](http://www.english-for-students.com/Omitting-That.html):

Comment: @Minty: I'm not sure, because all of the sentences include "you said". So as far as I can tell "he would" is playing the role of a complement of *say* in each sentence.

Comment: @LucianSava: "that" being optional in this context would make sense to me, but I can't figure out why it would sound wrong to include it.

Comment: I think that using *that* is never **really** wrong, perhaps superfluous?

Comment: None of them looks wrong to me, but (4) jars a little because 'like you said' is quite colloquial in tone while including 'that' makes the sentence a little more formal.

Comment: I think you're correct, and I think the reason is that the complementizer is not needed in any of them, but adds one more unstressed syllable without adding any information. The more unstressed syllables intrude between stresses, the more they get chewed up, and an optional syllable is most easily deleted before the fæspičrulz take over. To a certain extent it's stylistic, but it's in principle no different from any other phenomenon that shortens speech. There are lots of them, and they compete with phenomena that lengthen it.

Comment: Like @Kate, I find all four perfectly acceptable. The extra _that_ doesn’t add any level of formality to me, so I don’t find 4 jarring at all. I do find it jarring if we ‘expand’ _as/like_ to a noun phrase with one more _that_: “In exactly the way that you said that he would” is not ungrammatical to me, but clumsy enough that – I think – I would notice it. Naturally, I find **all** of them more mellifluous and natural without any _that_’s at all, but their presence doesn’t bother me in any of your four cases.

Comment: This reminds me a bit of that thing where complementiser _that_ is mandatorily blocked in embedded relative clauses if the relativiser is the subject of the complement clause. I mentioned it in [an old answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/181996/), but I still haven’t seen a proper treatment of this weird phenomenon anywhere. (Granted, I haven’t really looked very far, but I couldn’t find it in CGEL, which I thought was odd – though perhaps just down to my inability to use an index.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet that sounds like a very promising explanation.

Comment: John Lawler has the long and the short of it.

Answer (score 4):

You are reacting to stylistic expectations. *That* is optional in all four uses. As you add words that can also carry emphasis, it becomes more and more desirable to omit an optional element and thereby reduce the number of words that can be emphasized.

Martin Endley, in *Linguistic Perspectives on English Grammar*, has a section on optional "*that* clause complements":

> Another striking feature of that clause complements when they function
>   as DOs (direct objects) is that, under certain conditions, the use of
>   the complementizer becomes optional and may be omitted without
>   affecting the grammaticality of the sentence:
>
> (53) a. Dr. Endley knows (that) Ankara gets very cold in the winter.
>
> b. Dr. Endley told his mother (that) Ankara gets very cold in the
>   winter. (p. 372)

What are the conditions of omission? Endley provides three general guidelines that guide usage:

1. **Register**. More formal utterances tend to use *that*, and spoken English is more likely to omit it.
2. **The importance of information in the clause**. If the information is more significant, *that* is more likely to be used. If the information is mostly descriptive, *that* is less likely to be used.
3. **Distance between the main verb and the *that* clause**. Close proximity renders the that-clause optional; with more intermediate phrases, the need to emphasize the relation to the main verb with a *that*-headed clause grows.

Guideline 2 is most relevant to your examples. In (1):

> 1. You said that he would come to the party.

The information is stated in full, and so it can be read as relatively significant. *That* gives an added bit of emphasis. However, in (4):

> 4. He came to the party, just like you said that he would.

"That he would" is the only part of the clause. The that-clause mainly acts to remind readers that *you* said information similar to the first part of the sentence. Because the information in this clause isn't otherwise significant, it feels odd to emphasize it with *that*. 2 and 3 follow similar lines: if 2 feels marginally acceptable, it is only because emphasizing *that* would be less odd without the added emphasis of *just* before *like* or *as*. In other words, at least in 2 *that* isn't competing for attention.

Source: Endley, Martin J. *Linguistic Perspectives on English Grammar: A Guide for EFL Teachers*. Information Age Pub., 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Comments so far implied that the grammar was prinipally identical in all four examples. I disagree, and I would share the sentiment that the questionable examples are simply wrong, because the different sentence structure requires a different word order. This isn't clear cut, and from a descriptive perspective there's no wrong or right, as long as it's legitamte by virtue of common usage.

I simply reason that: In the more complex examples, if you preferentially expect the predicate to begin with the subject of the verbal phrase, then you will read "that" as a relative pronoun (rarely) or determiner "... just as you said *that* man would".

I'm not quite sure why it should differ in the former clause. I suspect it is because therein the main verb is in the matrix clause. In all other cases, the verb "say" is already in adposition. Maybe it could be said that it acts as conjunction itself, so no "that" is needed. This can be rectified by lifting the relative clause, *just as you said it, that he would*, which is more or less how it would be in German (genau wie du (es) gesagt hast, dass es passieren würde).

Consequently, we see a lot of *that that*, although the assumption about the origin of the conjunction is in fact from determinative usage, as far as I know.